# Angular component partial scss convention location

Tags: angular

I have created a partial scss file of a custom component. My question is, by convention, where should this file be located? inside the component folder? in src/themes? somewhere else? Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would put it under `src/assets/styles/partial.scss` & then update my angular.json as

```
"styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "src/assets/styles/partial.scss"
            ],
```

This is considering the fact that you are using both styles.css & scss files.